# Set MaterialDatePicker calender language to English only

Tags: android, material-design, materialdatepicker

I am using MaterialDatePicker in my android app project. The app also supports multiple local languages.
Now the issue is that when i select app langauge other then English the calendar language also changes to the selected one.
**How can i fix the calendar language to English only.**
Below is the code for the MaterialDatePicker:

```
val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
                .setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_MaterialCalendar)
                .setTitleText("Select Date")
                .setCalendarConstraints(
                    CalendarConstraints.Builder()
                        .setValidator(
                            DateValidatorPointBackward.now()
                        )
                        .build()
                )
                .build()
```

I have read the official document and also searched through stackoverflow, but haven't found anything related to this.